# Form is missing from forms list in SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

I created a workflow based on a list. My list shows that it's associated with the new workflow, however looking at the workflow, the form is not in the forms list used by this workflow. I don't know how the form was created (most likely 2010) since I've grabbed it from another site. I tested the workflow and it doesn't appear to be doing anything (should've sent me email for purchase approval). Any idea how to add the form to the workflow?